# File creation and attachment at Apigee platform

Tags: apigee

At Apigee platform, is there a way (policy or custom code) through which request payload content (JSon data) can be transformed to a file (an XML file) and this file can be sent as an attachment to the backend server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the apache mime jar to construct the multipart form-data with the incoming payload (xml in your case) using a java callout.

Answer (score 0):

Attachment finally translates to multipart form request.

Request should conform to RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867

I think you might need to do build the payload using custom code.